# Can I delete whole cassandra partition with CrudRepository based only on the partition key?

Tags: java, spring, cassandra, crud, default-constructor

Basically I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE experiment(
 experimentid varchar,
 description text,
 rt float,
 intensity float,
 mz float,
 identifier text,
 chemical_formula text,
 filename text,
 PRIMARY KEY ((experimentid),description, rt, intensity, mz, identifier, chemical_formula, filename)
);
```

with Experiment.java

```
@Table(name= "experiment")
public class Experiment implements Serializable{

@PrimaryKey
private ExperimentKey experimentKey;

public ExperimentKey getExperimentKey() {
    return experimentKey;
}
public void setExperimentKey(ExperimentKey experimentKey) {
    this.experimentKey = experimentKey;
}
}
```

and ExperimentKey.java

```
@PrimaryKeyClass
public class ExperimentKey implements Serializable {

@PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "experimentid",ordinal = 0,type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
@CassandraType(type=DataType.Name.VARCHAR)
private String experimentid;
@PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "description",ordinal = 1)
@CassandraType(type=DataType.Name.VARCHAR)
private String description;
@PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "rt",ordinal = 2)
@CassandraType(type=DataType.Name.FLOAT)
private Float rt;
@PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "intensity",ordinal = 3)
@CassandraType(type=DataType.Name.FLOAT)
private Float intensity;
@PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "mz",ordinal = 4)
@CassandraType(type=DataType.Name.FLOAT)
private Float mz;
@PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "identifier",ordinal = 5)
@CassandraType(type=DataType.Name.VARCHAR)
private String identifier;
@PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "chemical_formula",ordinal = 6)
@CassandraType(type=DataType.Name.VARCHAR)
private String chemical_formula;
@PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "filename",ordinal = 7)
@CassandraType(type=DataType.Name.VARCHAR)
private String filename;

//getters and setters

public ExperimentKey(){

}
}
```

and basically I want to implement the query below through crudrepository:

```
Delete * from experiment where experimentid='(something)';
```

I know I can SELECT based only on the partition key with findAllByExperimentKey_Experimentid(experimentid), but is it possible to do the same with delete? 
I tried deleteAllByExperimentKey_Experimentid(experimentid) but I am getting an error:

> Failed to instantiate void using constructor NO_CONSTRUCTOR with arguments

**EDIT 1**

Ok, so this is my ExperimentRepo.java

```
public interface ExperimentRepo extends CrudRepository<Experiment,ExperimentKey>{
     public void deleteAllByByExperimentKey_Experimentid(String expid);
}
```

and this is my ExperimentServiceImpl.java

```
@Service
public class ExperimentServiceImpl implements ExperimentService{

private ExperimentRepo experimentRepo;

@Autowired
public ExperimentServiceImpl(ExperimentRepo experimentRepo){
    this.experimentRepo=experimentRepo;
}
@Override
public void deleteAllExperimentByExperimentid(String expid){
    MapId id = id("experimentid", expid);
    experimentRepo.deleteAllByByExperimentKey_Experimentid(expid);
}
```

Not sure where I should use the MapId id = id("experimentid", < Serializable Value > ).

Comment: have you tried removeByExperimentKey ?

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!!! Do you mean I should change Repository and not use CrudRepository? Because this method does not exist in Crud, so I get the same error! I can use deleteByExperimentKey but this basically goes throu each row and deletes it, which takes very long time. What if I had millions of rows?! So, at the end of the day, how could someone delete a whole partition from Cassandra by providing only the partition key?

Comment: Try with MapId id = id("experimentid", <Serializable Value>); the use deleteById api ... if that doesnot work u can always go with the old fashioned way. You can write your own CQL statements.

String cql = "delete from experiment where experimentid = '123123123'";

cassandraOperations.execute(cql);

Comment: I did the above Edit but still getting the same error! Should I do add something more somewhere else?

Comment: Please help me out! I am quite a newbie! Is there any way to do this through CrudRepository?? I would really appreciate an example!